# What elements does the $\overline{ P(A)}$ have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let's assume U is universal set and A is some set as following:

$U = \{1,2,3\}$ and
$A = \{1,2\}$.

So we can deduct:

$\overline A = U\setminus A = \{3\}$

$\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$\mathcal{P}(\overline A) =\{\emptyset,\{3\}\}.$


So what elements does $\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)}$ contain? the complement of $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Is it just $\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)} = \mathcal{P}(U)\setminus\mathcal{P}(A)$? why?
or it might be $\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)} = U\setminus\mathcal{P}(A)$?

from my knowledge $\mathcal{P}(\overline A) \neq \mathcal{P}(U)\setminus \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(\overline A)\cup \mathcal{P}(A)=\mathcal{P}(U)$
but what can I assume about $\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)}$? I am not sure.

Or we might discuss it in general, for any universal set $U$, and any set $A\subseteq U$. so what we can say about $\overline{\mathcal{P}(A)}$?

Comment: Not very clear... The "universal set" is a tricky concept; you can use it to compute the "complement" of set $A$, but the subsets of $A$ are not element of $U$. Thus, you cannot use it to compute the complement of $\mathscr P (A)$.

Comment: Maybe in your exercise has been specified that the complement of the power set of $A$ is made of all subsets of $U$ that are not subsets of $A$...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. this exercise is not from my homework, i saw something simillar on wiki and got me thinking about the  complement  of $\mathcal{P}(A)$.
here is the original exercise : $P(A^c)\setminus\{\emptyset\}\subseteq P(A)^c$

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it depends on the set where you define $\mathcal{P}(A)$ to be in. Since you seem to assume that $A\subset U$, then it would be natural to take the complementary of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ with respect to $\mathcal{P}(U)$. You can definitely assume something else, although taking its complementary in $U$ makes no sense since $\mathcal{P}(A)\not\subset U $.